# Disable the Layer Preview in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

How can I remove/disable the Layer Preview link in Geoserver? I don't want normal user to login their account and go to Layer Preview to download the data, such as geojson data. I can't disable the WFS as well, i need to use WFS method. Can anyone give me some advise?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From data under security section in the far left bottom, disable read access for whatever role you want. Add new security rule, choose a path -Workspace + Access mode(Read, Write)- and assign role to that rule.